# gcc has been compiled but there is no gcc binary

Tags: linux, gcc

I have downloaded gcc-4.1.2 from http://gcc.petsads.us/releases/gcc-4.1.2/gcc-4.1.2.tar.bz2 and built with two commands

```
./configure
make
```

Now I can see g++ binary. But there is no gcc binary.

```
$ ls /opt/gcc-4.1.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/g++
/opt/gcc-4.1.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/g++

$ ls /opt/gcc-4.1.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/gcc
ls: cannot access /opt/gcc-4.1.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/gcc: No such file or directory
```

What did I miss?

Comment: I didn't want to install for all users.

Comment: @mahmood you dont have to install for all users, if you set up --prefix variable during configure

Comment: @xhudik: thanks for pointing that. Please add that to your answer

Comment: @mahmood - adding such info would not be good since your question is not about setting up configuration process ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. did you check whether `configure` and `make` went without error?
2. but less probable: did you run also `make install` which should install all binaries into appropriate directories?

Comment: There shouldn't be any error because the g++ binary is available. I didn't run "make install" because I didn't want to install for all users.

Comment: if one binary is built doesn't mean that no error happened. Most likely if you do not install it, no symlinks will be created (this can be your problem)

Answer (score 2):

The gcc binary is called `xgcc` until it is installed.